# Can I trigger a breakpoint on OpenGL errors in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ipad, debugging, opengl-es, xcode4

Is there any way I can set a symbolic breakpoint that will trigger when any OpenGL function call sets any state other than `GL_NO_ERROR`? Initial evidence suggests `opengl_error_break` is intended to to serve just that purpose, but it doesn't break.

Comment: You could create a background NSTimer that fires every 3 frames or so that monitors error codes and have it throw an exception / have a breakpoint.

Comment: That would come close to alerting me of error conditions immediately, but the main goal is give me a callstack at the time of the error so I can easily track down the offending call.

Comment: For reference, the code doesn't seem to work. I rolled my one: https://gist.github.com/3352303

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Lars' approach you can achieve this tracking of errors automatically, it is based on some preprocessor magic and generating stub functions.

I wrote a small [Python script](https://gist.github.com/1502925#file_gen_debug_header.py) which processes the OpenGL header (I used the Mac OS X one in the example, but it should also work with the one of iOS).

The Python script generates two files, [a header](https://gist.github.com/1502925#file_gl_debug_overwrites.h) to include in your project everywhere where you call OpenGL like this (you can name the header however you want):

```
#include "gl_debug_overwrites.h"
```

The header contains macros and function declarations after this scheme:

```
#define glGenLists _gl_debug_error_glGenLists
GLuint _gl_debug_error_glGenLists(GLsizei range);
```

The script also produces a [source file](https://gist.github.com/1502925#file_gl_debug_overwrites.c) in the same stream which you should save separately,  compile and link with your project.

This will then wrap all `gl*` functions in another function which is prefixed with `_gl_debug_error_` which then checks for errors similar to this:

```
GLuint _gl_debug_error_glGenLists(GLsizei range) {
    GLuint var = glGenLists(range);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR();
    return var;
}
```

Comment: Cool stuff! @MattWilding: I think Torsten deserves the bounty more than I do. Please change if this is still possible!

Comment: @LarsSchneider, The 24 hours expired, so it's yours forever. The best I can do is move the Green Checkmark. Thanks to you both for your input.

Comment: How do you use this Python script in XCode?

Comment: @Jonny The easiest should be to just add the generated [header](https://gist.github.com/1502925#file_gl_debug_overwrites.h) and [implementation](https://gist.github.com/1502925#file_gl_debug_overwrites.c) to your Xcode project, they have been generated on a Mac.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your OpenGL calls to call `glGetError` after every call in debug mode. Within the wrapper method create a conditional breakpoint and check if the return value of `glGetError` is something different than `GL_NO_ERROR`.

*Details:*

Add this macro to your project (from OolongEngine project):

`#define CHECK_GL_ERROR() ({ GLenum __error = glGetError(); if(__error) printf("OpenGL error 0x%04X in %s\n", __error, __FUNCTION__); (__error ? NO : YES); })`

Search for all your OpenGL calls manually or with an appropriate RegEx. Then you have two options exemplary shown for the `glViewport()` call:

1. Replace the call with `glViewport(...); CHECK_GL_ERROR()`
2. Replace the call with `glDebugViewport(...);` and implement `glDebugViewport` as shown in (1).

Comment: This would certainly work, but going back through a large project to sprinkle conditionally compiled `glGetError` calls everywhere is exactly what I don't want to have to do. I'm surprised there's not a symbol I can just break on.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what could get you out of the problem is to [capture OpenGL ES Frames](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html) (scroll down to "Capture OpenGL ES Frames"), which is now supported by Xcode. At least this is how I am debugging my OpenGL Games.

By capturing the frames when you know an error is happening you could identify the issue in the OpenGL Stack without too much effort.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, capturing frames is a very cool capability, and I use it extensively. Unfortunately, I have to first notice that OpenGL is in an error state, then manually capture the frame, then walk the calls for the frame to isolate the error. It works, but I would really like to just automatically break. It would save me some time, and seems like it should be possible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that you want to do it automatically... I'm not sure if it is possible with Xcode. Will see if I find something else